# Reload UIWebView from button with IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm creating an app that uses a UIWebView to display a schedule. I've added a button that when clicked downloads an updated schedule from a webserver. My attempt was to make that button's action also refresh the UIWebView however when using [iPadscheduleView reload]; it makes no effect.

My viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);

NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schedule.html"]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
[iPadscheduleView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url]];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

my IBAction for the button

```
-(IBAction)synctheschedule {
 NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.elitespark.com/schedule.html"]];
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schedule.html"];
[fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Popup" message:@"The schedule has been synced with the server." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Refresh" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];    
[iPadscheduleView reload];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that iPadScheduleView is non-null when you invoke reload?    NSLog(@"ipadSchedView is %@",iPadScheduleView);   will tell you.

Comment: iPadscheduleView is (null)   I'm not sure how to correct this?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by setting the delegate. I forgot to do that :P doh!